# c++ pthread in eclipse cant compile, in terminal is ok

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads

I'm trying to use pthread in eclipse (photon), end everytime i'm wave got error in compilation:

```
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -pthread -o "FG002_PartB_1st_Edition_Ver0.1"  ./I2C.o ./MCP23017.o ./MPU6050.o ./PCA9685.o   -l-pthread
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -l-pthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Or another from make, but that I'll add tommorow, it depends on settings. Of course i'd tried to find answer in google, and i'd find, nad try a lot of them, but nothing helped. I thing code is ok (copied from internet example, to be sre, it is ok, a few of them, and the same result, co it must be ok). 
As you see in code it is arm cross commpiller, but the same errors i have in normal compiller (in console too)

```
wowa@wowa-pc:~/eclipse-workspace/FG002_PartB_1st_Edition_Ver0.1$ g++ -pthread main.cpp
wowa@wowa-pc:~/eclipse-workspace/FG002_PartB_1st_Edition_Ver0.1$ ./a.outx: 0, y: 0
y increment finished
x increment finished
x: 100, y: 100
```

Comment: You might look up the -pthread  option.  Or try it (in stead of -l-pthread

Comment: Are you certain that g++ is the same as arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++? If they aren't the same the comparison isn't all that reliable.